# Debian Jessie, copy file on NFS share (autofs) at shutdown

Tags: debian, systemd, autofs

I'm on Jessie 8.1 so I use systemd to launch a service at shutdown. My service uses a script to copy a file on a NFS share (mounted by autofs).

It doesn't work, I know the script can copy a file on an NFS share and I know my service is really executing at shutdown.

I use autofs to mount my NFS share and I think the problem is that at shutdown when my script tries to copy the file, autofs is already shutdown, and the NFS share is unmounted, so it doesn't copy. I want to use after/before in the unit but how to target autofs? I don't have any autofs.service running.

What should I do?